# JDBC select query with join and like fails

Tags: select, join, jdbc, sql-like

I am trying to search the data in two tables by getting the last four numbers of a SSN as input from the user.

I have a JDBC query that is as follows:

```
`String sql = "SELECT N.NUMBER,N.LAST_NAME,N.FIRST_NAME,M.SSN,M.SEX,M.BIRTH_DATE"
             +"FROM" +" G.M_NAME_A N, G.M_ID_A M"
             +"WHERE" + "N.NUMBER = M.NUMBER"
             +"AND" + "M.SSN like 'l4ssn' ";'
```

It fails with either "FROM Keyword not found where expected" or "Invalid Column index".

Please help me format the query.

Comment: Print your sql variable.There might be concatenation issue.for that attach space before every sql keywords.

Answer (score 2):

yes, it should fail. Check your SQL, you're missing a space in front of "FROM", and ditto most anywhere you're concatenating strings.

Answer (score 0):

Change the SQL as follows. Space is added around FROM, WHERE and AND

```
String sql = "SELECT N.NUMBER,N.LAST_NAME,N.FIRST_NAME,M.SSN,M.SEX,M.BIRTH_DATE"
         +" FROM " +" G.M_NAME_A N, G.M_ID_A M"
         +" WHERE " + "N.NUMBER = M.NUMBER"
         +" AND " + "M.SSN like 'l4ssn' ";
```

Your query will look for `M.SSN` which is `14ssn` it's just like saying `M.SSN = '14ssn'`. If you want to use query something similar to `14ssn` use `M.SSN like '%14ssn%'` instead

Just on side note, use prepared statement instead of using the query parameter in your sql string.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html

Comment: Thank you for correcting and pointing me in the right direction. I shall update after testing with the new query.

Answer (score 0):

1、Change the SQL as follows. Space is added around FROM, WHERE and AND，If you follow what you write sql, sql stitching is so out：

```
String sql = "SELECT N.NUMBER,N.LAST_NAME,N.FIRST_NAME,M.SSN,M.SEX,M.BIRTH_DATEFROM G.M_NAME_A N, G.M_ID_A MWHEREN.NUMBER = M.NUMBERAND M.SSN like 'l4ssn' ";

String sql = "SELECT N.NUMBER,N.LAST_NAME,N.FIRST_NAME,M.SSN,M.SEX,M.BIRTH_DATE"
             +" FROM G.M_NAME_A N, G.M_ID_A M"
             +" WHERE N.NUMBER = M.NUMBER"
             -- modify +" AND" + "M.SSN like 'l4ssn' ";'
             +" AND  M.SSN like '%l4ssn%' ";
```

Comment: This will not work. Space next to WHERE.? Same with the AND as well.

Comment: Has just been modified, try again

Comment: <Same with the AND as well>.Is one such treatment

Comment: I am not the person who asked the question.

Comment: I guess that's exactly what I have answered right above to you.

Comment: I will let you know after I try.

Answer (score 0):

Try this query

```
String sql=" SELECT N.NUMBER,N.LAST_NAME,N.FIRST_NAME,M.SSN,M.SEX,M.BIRTH_DATE "+
           " FROM G.M_NAME_A N,G.M_ID_A M "+
           " WHERE N.NUMBER = M.NUMBER "+
           " AND M.SSN like 'l4ssn' ";
```

Comment: Why before and after every line.? Isn't it just generate proper SQL.?

Comment: @VallabhPatade one space sufficient before or after line,I just told because it looks nice to see and also for understanding.

Comment: I'll try and let you know the result. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
The question is resolved using the following query and PreparedStatement:
String l4ssn=("%"+l4ssn);
String sql = "SELECT N.NUMBER,N.LAST_NAME,N.FIRST_NAME,M.SSN,M.SEX,M.BIRTH_DATE"
     +" FROM " +" G.M_NAME_A N, G.M_ID_A M"
     +" WHERE " + "N.NUMBER = M.NUMBER"
     +" AND " + "M.SSN like ?";
PreparedStatement pstmt = new PreparedStatement(sql);
pstmt.setString(1,l4ssn);
```